# Returning boolean instead of value, re-creating .select method

Tags: ruby, boolean, return-value

I'm trying to re-create the `select` method using a `while` loop and `yield`. Below is my code:

```
def my_select(collection)
  count = 0
  newColl = []
  while collection.length > count
    if (collection[count] % 2 == 0)
      newColl.push(yield (collection[count]))
    end
    count += 1
  end
  newColl
end
```

When I run the following:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_select(arr) do |num|
  num.even?
end
```

I want this result:

```
[2, 4]
```

but I get this:

```
[true, true]
```

I get a boolean return instead of the actual value.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you push the result of `yield` (which can, but doesn't have to be boolean) instead of actual collection element. You should more add element based on what `yield` returns, like this:

```
element = collection[count]
newColl.push(element) if yield(element)
```

BTW I don't really get why you're checking the number parity inside of `my_select` method? It makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to:

```
def my_select(collection)
  count = 0
  newColl = []
  while collection.length > count
    if (collection[count] % 2 == 0)
      result = yield collection[count] # yield first
      newColl.push(collection[count]) if result # then push to newColl if required
    end
    count += 1
  end
  newColl
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_select(arr) {|num| num.even? }
#=> [2,4]
```

Though, your `newColl` collection is pretty much useless here.

**Edit**:
Since you mentioned about re-creating `select`, this might be an alternative:

```
def my_select(collection)
  # it iterates on the collection and filters the item for which the block return true, at the end, I compact the collection to remove nils
  collection.map do |item|
    item if yield(item)
  end.compact
end

# or 
def my_select(collection)
  # start with a blank array
  coll = []
  # iterate on collection
  collection.each do |item|
    # insert all those items for which the block returns true by yield(item)
    coll << item if yield(item)
  end
  # return the array
  coll
end

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
my_select(arr) {|num| num.even? }
#=> [2, 4]
```

Comment: You inlined the condition to the loop, whereas you should use the one provided in the block

Comment: based on the OP's code, I assumed his intention is to have an inline condition within my_select and he wants to use further block condition to filter. Obviously, I don't understand the intention here.